# Запись в конец файла без вычисления смещения

Tags: freebsd

Можно ли с помощью `vn_rdwr(9)` дописывать в конец файла, не вычисляя само смещение? Насколько я понял, есть ещё функции для записи из ядра *FreeBSD* в файл: `vn_write(9)`, `VOP_WRITE()`. В `VOP_ACCESS` можно выставить флаг `VAPPEND`. Но как этим пользоваться - не знаю. Где описаны (исходный код) функции типа `VOP_ACCESS_APV()` и `VOP_WRITE_APV()`?

Comment: Откуда нформация про VOP_ACCESS_APV() и VOP_WRITE_APV()?

Comment: @tutankhamun По цепочке дошел до vnode_if.h. Дальше: концы в воду.

Comment: Что пишете, если не секрет?

Comment: @tutankhamun пытаюсь понять как все устроено. С частью разобрался, но возникли подозрения что можно писать в файл по другому.

Comment: grep -R Вам в помощь...

Comment: @avp grep не находит. Если бы находил - не спрашивал бы. Есть подозрение что корни уходят в asm.

Comment: А у Вас все исходники? Смотрите Makefile, собирайте по частям. Кстати, этот файл (`vnode_if.h`) генерится шелловским скриптом. Посмотрите его.

Comment: @avp возможно вы правы и не хватает определенных файлов, генерируемых при компиляции. Проверю.

Answer (score 1):

На python, я бы долго не думал, если костыль надо наскоро забить:

```
import commands
import time
filename = 'big.log'
new_message = str( time.ctime() ) + ': New message'
commands.getoutput('/bin/echo "' + new_message + '" >> ' + filename )
```

Должно сработать, и копал бы я именно вокруг `>>` для нахождения исходных Сишных команд.

Comment: Вопрос был про запись из ядра.